# Unable to start Java applications on xfce4 desktop? - Screw you lightdm

Tags: java, linux, environment-variables

I used to use Debian's alternatives system to set 'global env' like `java, javac, javap` but I've read about the disadvantages.

So I added

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk/java
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

to my `~/.bashrc` and when I open my terminal I can use the commands as expected but my most of my shell scripts doesn't work anymore.

As you can see in the picture below they check if `$JAVA_HOME` exists and executes the following command which does nothing. When I enter `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` it works correctly. If I start the script in a terminal it works, too.

So it seems that `#!/bin/sh` doesn't `source .bashrc`? Changing it to `#!/bin/bash` doesn't solve the problem.

I tried to add the `export` commands to `/etc/profile` but this doesn't seem to get `sourced` at startup/login.

Does anyone have an idea or keywords? I think the solution is quite simple but at the moment I'm stuck.

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**
Starting the script in the bash terminal with `./something.sh` works fine. Right click and execute or 'Open with bash' (XFCE4 context menu) does nothing.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you will find [one](http://superuser.com/a/183980/283245) [of](http://superuser.com/q/409186/283245) [these](http://superuser.com/q/585528/283245) [superuser](http://superuser.com/q/426114/283245) questions helpful.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the default `sh` application in debian nowadays is **dash** rather than **bash**. This means that `/bin/sh` will not source any `.bash_rc` or `.bash_profile` and will also lack a lot of other functionality. You may want to change the default shell.

Comment: @RealSkeptic this is very interesting and seemed to be the solution but unfortunately it didn't work. But I have the feeling to get closer...

Comment: What did you do to change the default shell?

Comment: changed it with `chsh` back and forth.

Comment: No, that only changes this particular user's default shell. It doesn't change the link from `/bin/sh`. I think you'll need to change that through the alternatives system or some other administrative command (sorry I am sketchy, I'm not a sysadmin) . Try `ls -l /bin/sh` and see where it leads you.

Comment: Why not just set JAVA_HOME in the script directly?

Comment: Also, seeing your edit - it seems that it may get the `.bashrc` after all. Your problem is just in the graphical environment? If so, have you tried to log out of the X environment and log in again?

Comment: @WillShackleford I use some scripts that come with the application to start it (e.g. Intellij, Argo UML, launch4j, etc.). I have to change every script for every application. There must be a cleaner way.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes the problems seems to occur only in the graphical environment. Also simple scripts with `java -jar myJar.jar` don't work. I restarted the laptop several times now (without saving the session, but to be sure I'll clean the cache now) **UPDATE:** didn't work :(

Comment: Wrap the script with another script that logs to a file and run that in the graphical environment so you can see errors. eg  ./somescript.sh >somescript.log 2>./somescript.err

Comment: @WillShackleford very good idea. I get `./launch4j: 6: ./launch4j: java: not found` so it seems the in whatever shell desktop applications are launched has the wrong path variable and yes: if I add `echo $PATH` the logfile shows the very default path variable `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games` . I added the export lines in `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` but these files seemed not to get sourced on startup.

Comment: WillShackleford, @RealSkeptic, shoover added the solution if you're interested. thanks for your help.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and arrange it more appropriately to StackOverflow. The question should contain only the problem, including details and updates about things tried. But the solution should be moved to an **answer**. You are allowed to add your own answer and to accept it. This will remove the question from the "questions that need an answer" and also will clearly show anybody who searches for it that there is a solution even before reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding additional folders to your PATH variable in XFCE4 with LightDM will not work as expected! Shell scripts that use these additional commands and are started from the graphical environment will fail because the can't find the command. Logging the PATH variable while starting one of these scripts shows that the PATH variable is overwritten with the very default one. Why? Because LightDM hardcodes the PATH variable and overwrites it for the graphical environment. Screw you! Look [here](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/94971962/01_set-default-path.patch)!

Source: https://ljwo.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/global-path-in-debian-wheezy-xfce/

Disable it or use another DM.

Answer (score 1):

Bash loads .bashrc only when the shell is **interactive** and **non-login**. In your case the shell is **not interactive**, so .bashrc is not loaded.

.bashrc contains a check that prevents it from executing if the shell is not interactive. Usually the first thing .bashrc does is:

```
case $- in 
   *i*) ;;
     *) return;;
esac
```

This will prevent you from calling `source .bashrc` from your script.
The script **should** inherit from your parent shell, so you should be getting all variable that have been exported before you ran the script.

Also, the preferred shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env bash` which is more portable.

So in your case:
Open a terminal window. That will load .bashrc, but just to make sure, run `. .bashrc` and then `echo $JAVA_HOME` to verify that the variable was set correctly.

Then your script will simply be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
java -jar <whatever>
```

If you have some other script related variable that you want to set, you can do that by sourcing a "settings" script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source ~/settings.sh
echo $SOME_VAR_SET_IN_SETTINGS_SH
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. I've tried a very simple script `#!/bin/[ba]sh java -jar myJar.jar` with the same result. Nothing happens unless I start it in the bash shell.

Comment: @parboiledRice sometimes the default .bashrc contains a check that will prevent it from being loaded if the shell is not interactive. See updated answer for more info.